# GStreamer in Docker = overlays not working

Tags: docker, overlay, gstreamer

I need to stream a video from a server to a client, with a clock overlay. The server must be inside a Docker image.

Here is the server command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
    v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
    ! videorate ! videoscale \
    ! clockoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans 38" \
    ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=640,height=360,framerate=25/1 \
    ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay \
    ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000
```

And here is the client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
    udpsrc port=5000 \
    ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG, framerate=25/1 \
    ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

As you can try, this is working well. But when running the server from a Docker image, I get this warning and the process stops:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "clockoverlay"

Here is my Docker file:

```
from ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Me

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    openjdk-8-jre \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-tools \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENTRYPOINT exec \
gst-launch-1.0 \
    v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
    ! videorate ! videoscale \
    ! clockoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans 38" \
    ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=640,height=360,framerate=25/1 \
    ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay \
    ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000
```

What could I be missing? Is there any dependency I could add? Text overlays are not working either, so I suspected a font problem and tried to install fonts-liberation as well, without luck.

EDIT: I logged into my docker image, and gst-inspect-1.0 clockoverlay answers

> No such element or plugin 'clockoverlay'

Comment: check if package  "libpango1.0-0 libpango1.0-dev "  are present.

Comment: On the docker image I have libpango-1.0-0. On my computer I have libpango-1.0-0 and libpango1.0-0. Are you sure libpango1.0-0 is needed?

Comment: Yes as the clockoverlay plugin is Pango-based text rendering and overlay (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-clockoverlay.html)

Comment: I meant are you sure that I need libpango1.0-0 (no dash before the 1) and that libpango-1.0-0 (dash before the 1) is not enough? Could I need gstreamer1.0-x?

Comment: clockoverlay plugin is part of gstreamer1.0-plugins-base (make sure you have this) also  libpango1.0-0 and libpango-1.0-0  is the same.

Comment: OK so I definitely have gstreamer1.0-plugins-base and libpango-1.0-0 (apt-get install tells that I already have the newest version for both). Any other idea? I don't have gstreamer1.0-x (and can't find a way to install it for now), could it be needed?

Comment: gstreamer1.0-x  is definitely needed (https://packages.debian.org/sid/gstreamer1.0-x) to get clockoverlay working.

Comment: Yeah looks like, thanks for the confirmation. Still have to find how to get it on y image...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just needed to install gstreamer1.0-x as well.